# Symfony: Could not find driver

Tags: php, symfony

Im running symfony with xampp. Trying to connect to and create db trhough *doctrine framework*. When i write *doctrine:database:create* im answered with *Could not find driver*.
But my pdo driver works well. It is present in phpinfo, plus i can easily connect to db through the *pdo* constructor.
Here is my doctrine configs:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
    driver: pdo_mysql
    # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
    # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
    #server_version: '13'
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        App:
            is_bundle: false
            type: annotation
            dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
            prefix: 'App\Entity'
            alias: App
```

And my env:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/aihara"
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you don't have another php.ini where the pdo_mysql is disabled